# Using the squeel gem I keep getting an error. Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to do a group_by on a active record query using the squeel gem. I keep receiving this error -->

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (OCIError: ORA-00936: missing expression: SELECT "TO_ENTRIES".* FROM "TO_ENTRIES" WHERE ("TO_ENTRIES"."EMP_DEPT" LIKE any('PLTDUP', 'PLTINS') AND "TO_ENTRIES"."AUTH" = 'E' AND ("TO_ENTRIES"."APPROVE_DISAPPROVE" LIKE '1' OR "TO_ENTRIES"."APPROVE_DISAPPROVE" LIKE '2'))): app/controllers/entry_controller.rb:115:in `index'
```

If I leave off the `group_by` it works problem is I really need the group_by on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
entry_by_start_date = Entry.where{(emp_dept.like any t) & (auth == 'E') & (approve_disapprove.like_any a_d)}.group_by {|i| i.leave_start.to_date}
entry_by_end_date = Entry.where{(emp_dept.like any t) & (auth == 'E') & (approve_disapprove.like_any a_d)}.group_by {|i| i.leave_end.to_date}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
entry_by_start_date = Entry
                        .where{(emp_dept.like any t) & (auth == 'E') & (approve_disapprove.like_any a_d)}
                        .group(:leave_start)
```

```
entry_by_end_date = Entry
                      .where{(emp_dept.like any t) & (auth == 'E') & (approve_disapprove.like_any a_d)}
                      .group(:leave_end)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer unfortunalty I need the to_date for the group due to a calendar I have that uses dates. I get this error now ctionView::Template::Error (OCIError: ORA-00936: missing expression: SELECT "TO_ENTRIES".* FROM "TO_ENTRIES" WHERE "TO_ENTRIES"."EMP_DEPT" LIKE any('PLTDUP', 'PLTINS') AND "TO_ENTRIES"."AUTH" = 'E' AND ("TO_ENTRIES"."APPROVE_DISAPPROVE" LIKE '1' OR "TO_ENTRIES"."APPROVE_DISAPPROVE" LIKE '2') GROUP BY "TO_ENTRIES"."LEAVE_START", "TO_ENTRIES"."LEAVE_END"):
@user3409950

Answer (score 0):

The error OCIError: ORA-00936: missing expression:

happens due to forget to the list of the columns in the select or grouping

You can try

```
entry_by_start_date = Entry.group(:leave_start).select{[leave_start.to_date]}.where{(emp_dept.like any t) & (auth == 'E') & (approve_disapprove.like_any a_d)}

entry_by_end_date = Entry.group(:leave_end).select{[ leave_end.to_date]}.where{(emp_dept.like any t) & (auth == 'E') & (approve_disapprove.like_any a_d)}
```

Comment: I tried your answer and it still doesn't work due to me needing the leave_start.to_date and leave_end.to_date @Rajarshi Das

Comment: Thank you for your help but unfortunately Its still not working correctly. I still get this error OCIError: ORA-00936: missing expression: SELECT "LEAVE_START"."TO_DATE", "LEAVE_END"."TO_DATE" FROM "TO_ENTRIES" WHERE "TO_ENTRIES"."EMP_DEPT" LIKE any('PLTDUP', 'PLTINS') AND "TO_ENTRIES"."AUTH" = 'E' AND ("TO_ENTRIES"."APPROVE_DISAPPROVE" LIKE '1' OR "TO_ENTRIES"."APPROVE_DISAPPROVE" LIKE '2') GROUP BY "TO_ENTRIES"."LEAVE_START", "TO_ENTRIES"."LEAVE_END"@Rajarshi Das

Comment: use [] brackets see my posts

Comment: Same issue I really appreciate your help ActionView::Template::Error (OCIError: ORA-00936: missing expression: SELECT "LEAVE_START"."TO_DATE", "LEAVE_END"."TO_DATE" FROM "TO_ENTRIES" WHERE "TO_ENTRIES"."EMP_DEPT" LIKE any('PLTDUP', 'PLTINS') AND "TO_ENTRIES"."AUTH" = 'E' AND ("TO_ENTRIES"."APPROVE_DISAPPROVE" LIKE '1' OR "TO_ENTRIES"."APPROVE_DISAPPROVE" LIKE '2') GROUP BY "TO_ENTRIES"."LEAVE_START", "TO_ENTRIES"."LEAVE_END"): @Rajarshi Das